# How to get the target of a shortcut?

Tags: matlab, file

How can I resolve a shortcut to its ultimate target on Windows programmatically?

<sub>I specify "ultimate" above to include the general case
shortcut → shortcut_1 →… → shortcut_n → target, in which there may be one or more "intervening" shortcut(s) in reference chain between `shortcut` and `target`.
Also, I specify "programmatically" to rule out solutions that require interactive use of some feature of the MATLAB GUI.</sub>

(On Unix systems, one way to resolve shortcuts is to use something like `system(['readlink ' shortcut])`, or even better, if available, `system(['readlink -f ' shortcut])`.  But I have not been able to find anything like this on Windows.)

Answer (score 1):

If you open the shortcut file and read the first line you should see it.

```
>>fID=fopen(shortcutpath);
>>C=fgetl(fID);
C =
*some weird string* *filepath* *some other weird string*
```

Then with regexp you can find it easily.

Comment: But perhaps you were not talking about file shortcuts in windows but about some other shortcuts (because I don't see the point of having a chain of shortcuts in that case), sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: Upvoted this because it seems to be part the solution to get the resulting location of the ultimate file. If you just want to open the ultimate file it is much easier as shown in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your goal is just to open the shortcut to its destination, it seems to be as easy as on unix. Simply use this code to open a shortcut named sc in your current directory:

```
!sc.lnk  % Equivalent to system('sc.lnk')
```

If the file is not in your current directory you need to add the path of course. If the shortcut refers to a shortcut it automatically ends up on the final result.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using COM.

Example:

```
server = actxserver('WScript.Shell');
path = server.CreateShortcut('D:\temp.lnk').TargetPath;
server.delete;
```

As Windows [doesn't allow](https://superuser.com/questions/425884/how-to-make-shortcut-to-another-shortcut) a shortcut to a shortcut, you get the "ultimate" target. :)